# Check if request came from mobile or web

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Is there a way for Passport to check if request came from mobile or web app when doing authentication? Because if request came from the web I want to return a view otherwise return a json payload.

Comment: It's best to return the same stuff regardless of the interface.  If you have absolutely no choice, be sure to have `Vary: User-Agent` in your response headers so that responses for one interface are not cached.

Answer (score 5):

This is my opinion,you can check user-agent in the  request header ,its look like this(came from windows):

> user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 **(Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)** AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36

and this is came from my iPhone

> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 **(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X)** AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1

and this is Android

> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 **(Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T)** AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Mobile Safari/537.36

so you can figer it out from user-agent,which request came from mobile or pc

Answer (score 3):

If you have two different clients expecting different results, then you should explicitly send different requests, not try to guess which response is wanted from some header that isn't necessarily reliable.  Plus, there's nothing keeping a mobile device from also accessing the web interface.  You can either vary the path or vary a query string.

So, from web, you might use `/login` and from mobile, you might use `/login-json` or some different path that indicates you want json.

Or from web, you might use `/login` and from mobile, you might use `/login?type=json`.

I would NOT recommend using the user-agent header to detect the intent of the request.  Instead, specify the intent directly in the request.